# Force PhantomJS execution with JavaScript error

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have a third-party script that is throwing an error message in the console. The webpage renders fine in the browser and functions correctly. However, when I use PhantomJS to test the webpage, the script would stop execution when it reaches the page error.

So I was wondering if there is any way I can force PhantomJS to continue execution even when there is error on the page.

Comment: No, the only way is to fix the error. There are shims that may work for you. Maybe a script wasn't loaded and the error is an undefined variable in which case you can try some SSL related commandline options. This is all very vague.

Comment: @ArtjomB. actually the error also occur in the webpage, it's in a compressed form so I can't really make out what does it do either. I have tried both SSL related option (ignore-ssl-error=true and ssl-protocol=any), but I don't believe that is the cause in this case

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS is pretty notorious for having an outdated WebKit version ( at least the versions before 2.0 ), so things like `Function#bind` might not work. So most likely your script is just breaking because of this older WebKit version, there isn't really a flag you can switch to fix that.

Try using the latest version of PhantomJS first. If that doesn't work then the best thing you can do is enable error logging inside your PhantomJS script, run it manually and then try to fix the errors.

Here is some example code on how to get JavaScript error messages and stack traces in a PhantomJS script.

```
page.onError = function (msg, trace) {
 console.log(msg);
 trace.forEach(function(item) {
   console.log('  ', item.file, ':', item.line);
 });
};
```